# how to convert JSON string from GSON library to JSON Object?

Tags: java, android, ios, json, gson

I know some threads have similar question, but I can't find the solution for me.

I am a beginner in mobile development. I little bit confused how to convert `JSON` `string` to normal `JSON`.

so I have `JSON` as `string` like below, this `json` `string` is generated from `GSON` that convert `Java` object to this `JSON` `string`:

> products=%5B%7B%22customers_basket_date_added%22%3A%222019-04-22%2012%3A28%3A41%22%2C%22customers_basket_id%22%3A4%2C%22customers_basket_product%22%3A%7B%22attributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22attributes_price%22%3A%220.0%22%2C%22categories_id%22%3A8%2C%22categories_name%22%3A%22Kemasan%20Botol%22%2C%22customers_basket_quantity%22%3A6%2C%22images%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22isSale_product%22%3A%220%22%2C%22language_id%22%3A0%2C%22motorist_id%22%3A0%2C%22motorist_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id_jenis_products%22%3A0%2C%22qty_orders_max%22%3A12%2C%22qty_orders_min%22%3A6%2C%22qty_promo_bought%22%3A0%2C%22trans_limit%22%3A0%2C%22trans_live%22%3A0%2C%22manufacturers_id%22%3A0%2C%22parent_id%22%3A0%2C%22products_description%22%3A%22PROMO%20APRIL%20MURAH%21%5Cu003cbr%5Cu003e%5Cr%5CnRekomendasi%20harga%20jual%20warung%20Rp%203.500%2Fbotol%5Cu003cbr%5Cu003e%5Cr%5CnUntung%20Rp%201.300%20%2859%25%29%5Cu003cbr%5Cu003e%5Cr%5CnPembelian%20min%206%20botol%2C%20maks%2012%20botol%22%2C%22final_price%22%3A%222200.0%22%2C%22products_id%22%3A140%2C%22products_image%22%3A%22resources%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Fproduct_images%2F1555722212.promo-larutan-kakitiga.jpg%22%2C%22products_liked%22%3A0%2C%22products_model%22%3A%22%22%2C%22products_name%22%3A%22PROMO%20Cap%20Kaki%20Tiga%20Botol%20200%20ml%22%2C%22products_ordered%22%3A0%2C%22products_price%22%3A%222200.0%22%2C%22products_quantity%22%3A1%2C%22products_status%22%3A0%2C%22products_tax_class_id%22%3A0%2C%22products_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22products_weight%22%3A%221%22%2C%22products_weight_unit%22%3A%22Btl%22%2C%22sort_order%22%3A0%2C%22tax_class_id%22%3A0%2C%22tax_priority%22%3A0%2C%22tax_rates_id%22%3A0%2C%22tax_zone_id%22%3A0%2C%22total_price%22%3A%2213200.0%22%7D%2C%22customers_basket_product_attributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22customers_id%22%3A0%7D%5D&status=0

that JSON string is generated from

```
new Gson().toJson(cartItemsList)
```

and that `cartItemsList` is an instance of class `CartProduct`

```
public class CartProduct {


    @SerializedName("customers_id")
    @Expose
    private int customersId;
    @SerializedName("customers_basket_id")
    @Expose
    private int customersBasketId;
    @SerializedName("customers_basket_date_added")
    @Expose
    private String customersBasketDateAdded;
    @SerializedName("customers_basket_product")
    @Expose
    private ProductDetails customersBasketProduct;
    @SerializedName("customers_basket_product_attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<CartProductAttributes> customersBasketProductAttributes = new ArrayList<CartProductAttributes>();



    public int getCustomersId() {
        return customersId;
    }

    public void setCustomersId(int customersId) {
        this.customersId = customersId;
    }

    public int getCustomersBasketId() {
        return customersBasketId;
    }

    public void setCustomersBasketId(int customersBasketId) {
        this.customersBasketId = customersBasketId;
    }

    public String getCustomersBasketDateAdded() {
        return customersBasketDateAdded;
    }

    public void setCustomersBasketDateAdded(String customersBasketDateAdded) {
        this.customersBasketDateAdded = customersBasketDateAdded;
    }

    public ProductDetails getCustomersBasketProduct() {
        return customersBasketProduct;
    }

    public void setCustomersBasketProduct(ProductDetails customersBasketProduct) {
        this.customersBasketProduct = customersBasketProduct;
    }

    public List<CartProductAttributes> getCustomersBasketProductAttributes() {
        return customersBasketProductAttributes;
    }

    public void setCustomersBasketProductAttributes(List<CartProductAttributes> customersBasketProductAttributes) {
        this.customersBasketProductAttributes = customersBasketProductAttributes;
    }

}
```

and the class `CartProductAttributes`

```
public class CartProductAttributes implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("customers_basket_id")
    @Expose
    private int customersBasketId;
    @SerializedName("products_id")
    @Expose
    private String productsId;
    @SerializedName("option")
    @Expose
    private Option option;
    @SerializedName("values")
    @Expose
    private List<Value> values = new ArrayList<Value>();


    public CartProductAttributes() {
    }


    public int getCustomersBasketId() {
        return customersBasketId;
    }

    public void setCustomersBasketId(int customersBasketId) {
        this.customersBasketId = customersBasketId;
    }

    public String getProductsId() {
        return productsId;
    }

    public void setProductsId(String productsId) {
        this.productsId = productsId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The option
     */
    public Option getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param option
     *     The option
     */
    public void setOption(Option option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The values
     */
    public List<Value> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param values
     *     The values
     */
    public void setValues(List<Value> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }



    //********** Describes the kinds of Special Objects contained in this Parcelable Instance's marshaled representation *********//

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }



    //********** Writes the values to the Parcel *********//

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel_out, int flags) {
        parcel_out.writeValue(customersBasketId);
        parcel_out.writeValue(productsId);
        parcel_out.writeParcelable(option, flags);
        parcel_out.writeList(values);
    }



    //********** Generates Instances of Parcelable class from a Parcel *********//

    public static final Creator<CartProductAttributes> CREATOR = new Creator<CartProductAttributes>() {

        // Creates a new Instance of the Parcelable class, Instantiating it from the given Parcel
        @Override
        public CartProductAttributes createFromParcel(Parcel parcel_in) {
            return new CartProductAttributes(parcel_in);
        }

        // Creates a new array of the Parcelable class
        @Override
        public CartProductAttributes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CartProductAttributes[size];
        }
    };



    //********** Retrieves the values from the Parcel *********//

    protected CartProductAttributes(Parcel parcel_in) {
        this.customersBasketId = parcel_in.readInt();
        this.productsId = parcel_in.readString();

        this.option = parcel_in.readParcelable(Option.class.getClassLoader());

        this.values = new ArrayList<Value>();
        parcel_in.readList(values, Value.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

and here is the ProductDetails class

```
public class ProductDetails implements Parcelable {


    @SerializedName("products_id")
    @Expose
    private int productsId;
    @SerializedName("products_quantity")
    @Expose
    private int productsQuantity;
    @SerializedName("products_model")
    @Expose
    private String productsModel;
    @SerializedName("products_image")
    @Expose
    private String productsImage;
    @SerializedName("products_price")
    @Expose
    private String productsPrice;
    @SerializedName("discount_price")
    @Expose
    private String discountPrice;
    @SerializedName("products_date_added")
    @Expose
    private String productsDateAdded;
    @SerializedName("products_last_modified")
    @Expose
    private String productsLastModified;
    @SerializedName("products_date_available")
    @Expose
    private String productsDateAvailable;
    @SerializedName("products_weight")
    @Expose
    private String productsWeight;
    @SerializedName("products_weight_unit")
    @Expose
    private String productsWeightUnit;
    @SerializedName("products_status")
    @Expose
    private int productsStatus;
    @SerializedName("products_ordered")
    @Expose
    private int productsOrdered;
    @SerializedName("products_liked")
    @Expose
    private int productsLiked;
    @SerializedName("language_id")
    @Expose
    private int languageId;
    @SerializedName("products_name")
    @Expose
    private String productsName;
    @SerializedName("products_description")
    @Expose
    private String productsDescription;
    @SerializedName("products_url")
    @Expose
    private String productsUrl;
    @SerializedName("products_viewed")
    @Expose
    private int productsViewed;
    @SerializedName("products_tax_class_id")
    @Expose
    private int productsTaxClassId;
    @SerializedName("tax_rates_id")
    @Expose
    private int taxRatesId;
    @SerializedName("tax_zone_id")
    @Expose
    private int taxZoneId;
    @SerializedName("tax_class_id")
    @Expose
    private int taxClassId;
    @SerializedName("tax_priority")
    @Expose
    private int taxPriority;
    @SerializedName("tax_rate")
    @Expose
    private String taxRate;
    @SerializedName("tax_description")
    @Expose
    private String taxDescription;
    @SerializedName("tax_class_title")
    @Expose
    private String taxClassTitle;
    @SerializedName("tax_class_description")
    @Expose
    private String taxClassDescription;
    @SerializedName("categories_id")
    @Expose
    private int categoriesId;
    @SerializedName("categories_name")
    @Expose
    private String categoriesName;
    @SerializedName("categories_image")
    @Expose
    private String categoriesImage;
    @SerializedName("categories_icon")
    @Expose
    private String categoriesIcon;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private int parentId;
    @SerializedName("sort_order")
    @Expose
    private int sortOrder;
    @SerializedName("isLiked")
    @Expose
    private String isLiked;
    @SerializedName("manufacturers_id")
    @Expose
    private int manufacturersId;
    @SerializedName("manufacturers_name")
    @Expose
    private String manufacturersName;
    @SerializedName("manufacturers_image")
    @Expose
    private String manufacturersImage;
    @SerializedName("manufacturers_url")
    @Expose
    private String manufacturersUrl;
    @SerializedName("date_added")
    @Expose
    private String dateAdded;
    @SerializedName("last_modified")
    @Expose
    private String lastModified;

    @SerializedName("isSale_product")
    @Expose
    private String isSaleProduct;


    @SerializedName("attributes_price")
    @Expose
    private String attributesPrice;
    @SerializedName("final_price")
    @Expose
    private String productsFinalPrice;
    @SerializedName("total_price")
    @Expose
    private String totalPrice = "";

    @SerializedName("customers_basket_quantity")
    @Expose
    private int customersBasketQuantity;

    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

    @SerializedName("motorist_id")
    @Expose
    private long mMotoristId = 0;

    @SerializedName("motorist_name")
    @Expose
    private String mMotoristName = "";

    @SerializedName("qty_orders_min")
    @Expose
    private int mQuantityMin = 0;

    @SerializedName("qty_orders_max")
    @Expose
    private int mQuantityMax = 0;

    @SerializedName("id_jenis_products")
    @Expose
    private int mProductType = 0;

    @SerializedName("trans_limit")
    @Expose
    private int mQuantityPromoLimit = 0;

    @SerializedName("trans_live")
    @Expose
    private int mQuantityPromoLive = 0;

    @SerializedName("qty_promo_bought")
    @Expose
    private int mQuantityPromoBought = 0;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder tempToString = new StringBuilder("\n--- ProductDetails ---\n");
        tempToString.append("productsId: ").append(productsId).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("productsName: ").append(productsName).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("categoriesId: ").append(categoriesId).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("categoriesName: ").append(categoriesName).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("productsQuantity: ").append(productsQuantity).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("productsDateAdded: ").append(productsDateAdded).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("totalPrice: ").append(totalPrice).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("minQuantity: ").append(mQuantityMin).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("maxQuantity: ").append(mQuantityMax).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("mProductType: ").append(mProductType).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("mQuantityPromoLimit: ").append(mQuantityPromoLimit).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("mQuantityPromoLive: ").append(mQuantityPromoLive).append("\n");
        tempToString.append("mQuantityPromoBought: ").append(mQuantityPromoBought).append("\n");
        return tempToString.toString();
    }


}
```

and I want to convert that string JSON to be real JSON, for example like this:

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}
```

so I can read and replicate that `JSON`, and send it as `JSON` string from my iOS device to server using swift programming language. because I need to post that `JSON` string in the request body like this:

[image]

I get this `JSON` `string` from our android developer. this `JSON` `string` is generated from `GSON` library in Android, and it converts from Java Object to `JSON` string like that. unfortunately the android developer is also not understand how to convert it to real `JSON`, not `JSON` `string`.

Comment: That is an encoded string, use UrlDecoder.decode (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to decode it into a readable JSON String.

Comment: can you post what you have tried while parsing?

Comment: I'm not sure how do you want to convert given `JSON` to required format. Data do not fit. Where is the `Cake` and `donut` in encoded string?